# How to type matrices as options in a Multiple choice question paper?

Tags: matrices, exam

I want to set a multiple choice question paper for a series test on matrices and determinants. In some of the questions I have to give matrices as options. 
For other options I am using

```
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice
\end{oneparchoices}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are there the matrix small or normal sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{smallpmatrix}{%
    \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}%
    }{%
    \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question Question with regular matrices.
    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$
        \choice $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}$
    \end{oneparchoices}
    \question Question with smaller matrices.
    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice $\begin{smallpmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallpmatrix}$
        \choice $\begin{smallpmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{smallpmatrix}$
    \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```